# JQuery 1.8.3. Selector Function Not Working in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Script

```
$('#ListBox1 option').click(function () {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Service/AddEditService.aspx/GetPDF',
        data: JSON.stringify({ "fileName": $(this).attr("value") }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (msg) {
            window.open('../GeneratePDF.aspx?fileName=' + msg.d);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

The debugger line is never hit In IE but it does in Chrome and Firefox.

.ASPX

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server"  ClientIDMode="Static"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Is there a known bug or something? I can't seem to find an answer anywhere on the web.

Comment: Use the developer tools (F12) to inspect what the actual ID of the control is. Web Forms is notorious for changing your element ids.

Comment: I set the id to static. Checking the ID, It is ListBox1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector appears to be working fine as can be seen:

```
$('#ListBox1 option').first().css('background-color', 'red');
```

Rather the onclick is not firing for the option items. This may be a limitation of ie. You can add an onclick to the listbox, but not the option:

```
$('#ListBox1').click(function () {
    alert('listbox');
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/25HeW/2/

as you have stated, this works in chrome, but not ie.

UPDATE: 
The following can be used if you're looking for which item was selected

```
$('#ListBox1').click(function () {
    var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex]
    var text = 'value: ' + selected.value + ' text: '+ selected.label;
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: The ClientIDMode="static"

Comment: Also: you can use the Listbox click event and figure out the selected item.

Comment: That worked like a charm man. It makes me a little sad that IE doesn't play nice like the other browsers.